# In trac, is it possible to use trac variables -- like the list of Reports -- in wiki pages?

Tags: trac

Is it possible to use trac data, for example a list of reports, or a list of issues, in the trac wiki?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On wiki pages you can use macros. For example:

**TicketQuery**: macro listing tickets that match certain criteria.

**RecentChanges**: List all pages that have recently been modified, grouping them by the day they were last modified.

Or you can develop own macro. See more detail about wikimacros on [WikiMacros](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiMacros#AvailableMacros) page.